# Opening a video file from local drive as buffer and write it into new file

Tags: python, file, video, ffmpeg, buffer

I have multiple broken video files of one same video I need to join them together as one video again but when I tried this

```
import os
path = 'C:/temp/test'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    mainFile = open('C:/temp/main.mp4','ab')
    with open(path+'/'+file,'rb') as read:
        print (read)
        mainFile.write(read)
mainFile.close()
```

It threw an Error saying

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not file
```

So I don't know how do I make a video file buffer. I tried googling it and I found something called ffmpeg but it's a third party app. All I need is buffer of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `open()` returns a `file` object rather than the content of the file.  The error occurs because a `file` object is being passed into `write()`.

You can call `read()` method of a `file` object to read and return the content of the file.

Try

```
import os
path = 'C:/temp/test'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    mainFile = open('C:/temp/main.mp4','ab')
    with open(path+'/'+file,'rb') as f:
        mainFile.write(f.read()) 
mainFile.close()
```